# Whiptail on boot

Tags: linux, user-interface, whiptail

Just wondering if it's possible to launch a Whiptail UI on boot without user login.

```
http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail
```

The examples I have seen display when a user logs in via SSH. I'm looking for the UI to launch in the console window without user login.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It's very possible, but it also depends on details of your operating system -- it'd be done differently on a systemd-based distribution than a SysV init system, and differently there from somewhere using upstart, etc. The only way it would be a completely generic linux question rather than an OS-specific one is if you wanted the kernel to use your program that calls whiptail as init (PID 1), and that's not likely to be what you want. :)

Comment: Sorry I should of been clearer on the OS. I'm looking to achieve this on CentOS 6.5. This is also going to be a virtual machine, so when the user powers the VM on I want them to be presented with a whiptail style UI rather than the normal login console. I don't want to use X, because the build is configured as a basic server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a user whose shell is your `whiptail` program, and configure that user's account to be automatically logged in on TTY1.

On CentOS 6, you'll want to edit or override `/etc/init/start-ttys.conf` to not run a default TTY on tty1 (you can see the logic that's already in place to not do this in runlevel 5, and extend it to always be the case -- or use runlevel 5, and make the appropriate changes to block X invocation), and add your own TTY1 handler for the target account with autologin enabled.

This new config file (to be placed in `/etc/init`) might look like the following, if you named your account `menuuser`:

```
stop on runlevel [S016]
respawn
instance tty1
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin menuuser tty1
```

Answer (score 0):

By editing /etc/inittab it would be possible to run some other program than agetty on one or more virtual consoles. Usually agetty is used to give a login prompt to let users login.

By replacing agetty with some more or less custom program that program will be started by the root user. You probably want such a program to call setuid to continue running as some other user.

Another way to solve this would be to start the program from some startup script like rc.local.

If you are looking for some graphical program on the login screen it might be easier to start X from rc.local, maybe with some xdm functionality. It was many years since I did this, but I once had an xdm login screen with a serial terminal showing any input from the serial line.